# Automating CTRL+C (^+C) as part of a script?

Tags: shell-script

I have this following script which starts an SSH tunnel for port 80, installs PHPmyadmin, and then automatically deletes it after 2 hours (`sleep` timeout), from security reasons.

What I want to automize is leaving the tunnel. In now that to exit from the tunnel, I should execute CTRL+C after 2 hours, but I don't want to do it manually. I want it to be automatic as well. What could I add to the following script to automize quitting from the tunnel?

```
bash /dev/fd/4 4<< 'EOF0'    

    #!/bin/bash -x

# 1. Preface:

    # Make sure you closed port 3306 for good. !!!!!!!!!

    # Start an SSH tunnel:

        ssh WORK-USER@SERVER-IP -L 80:localhost:80

# 2. Install commands:

    sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin -y
    sudo phpenmod mcrypt mbstring
cat << EOF1 >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
EOF1
    sudo service apache2 restart

# 3. Delayed-uninstall commands:

    sleep 2h
    sudo phpdismod mcrypt mbstring
    sudo apt-get purge phpmyadmin -y
    sudo service apache2 restart
    sed -i 's/Include \/etc\/phpmyadmin\/apache.conf/ /g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
    # Sed: First forward slash == substitute. Last major three == diff, global, address.

EOF0
```

We have reached the end of the script. Let's assume 2 hours have passed but I am still on tunneling mode and left the computer; How could I ensure I quite tunneling mode automatically when the script ended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To terminate (hang up) the parent shell, you could simply `kill -SIGHUP $PPID`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a cron job that kill the process, write the entry from your script with PID, and the time+2hs to run 
Just my 2 cents!

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering. I didn't think of a command that kills it but I wonder why you suggest a cron job as this can be done directly from the script, after the sleep. I suggest you would example how you would target the tunneling code with the kill command.